# How long will rails try to make a http post request from within a action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My rails application makes a http post request to a url endpoint during a controller actions execution.

If that endpoint is down for whatever reason, how long will rails take to figure this out?  Is this configurable?

Comment: How are you making the POST request? Chances are whatever tool you're using has a timeout option. It may also depend on your web server, which the initial request will timeout at some point.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how the request is being made. If you're using ActiveResource, the default timeout is 60 seconds. ( http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveResource/Base.html )